# Netmiko - SSH Exception error while configuring Juniper switch

Tags: python, netmiko

I am trying the following simple python code and getting below errors which i am not sure why I am getting the error. Any help will be appreciated:

Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> from netmiko import juniper
>>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler
>>> from netmiko import file_transfer
>>> from netmiko import pprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'pprint' from 'netmiko' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netmiko/__init__.py)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> 
>>> ptxrtr = {
... 'device_type': 'juniper_junos',
... 'ip': '192.168.50.11',
... 'username': 'test',
... 'password': 'abc123'
... }
>>> ptx = ConnectHandler(**ptxrtr)
>>> ptx.is_alive()
True
>>> ptx.send_config_set('set interfaces lo1 description netmiko_config_change_test2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 699, in recv
    out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/buffered_pipe.py", line 164, in read
    raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 569, in _read_channel_expect
    new_data = self.remote_conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 701, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1875, in send_config_set
    new_output = self.read_until_pattern(pattern=re.escape(cmd.strip()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 651, in read_until_pattern
    return self._read_channel_expect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 579, in _read_channel_expect
    raise NetmikoTimeoutException(
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoTimeoutException: Timed-out reading channel, data not available.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few edits to your code. You can use the code below by editing it according to the username/password and interface structure of the device you are connecting to.

```
from netmiko import juniper
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# Establish a connection to the router
juniper = {
    'device_type': 'juniper',
    'host':   'device_IP',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'port' : 22,
}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**juniper)

# Edit the candidate configuration
config_commands = ['set interfaces lo0 unit 0 description netmiko_config_change_test2']
output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands, exit_config_mode=False)
print(output)

# Commit the config changes
output = net_connect.commit()
print(output)

output = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces lo0 unit 0 description')
print(output)

net_connect.disconnect()
```

**Sample Output**

```
configure 
Entering configuration mode
Users currently editing the configuration:
  lab terminal p0 (pid 77840) on since 2022-08-25 21:01:02 UTC, idle 00:01:13
      {master:0}[edit]

{master:0}[edit]
lab@leaf3-qfx# set interfaces lo0 unit 0 description netmiko_config_change_test2 

{master:0}[edit]
lab@leaf3-qfx# 
commit
configuration check succeeds
commit complete

{master:0}[edit]
lab@leaf3-qfx# 
description netmiko_config_change_test2;
```